# Unknown error in communication between Arduino and nodejs script

Tags: node.js, arduino

I'm trying to send a two-letter string from a nodejs script to Arduino (e.g "cc") and I'm getting no errors, but the arduino is not responding in the way it is supposed to.

The RX led is flashing, so I think I'm doing something wrong on the Arduino side, but I have no clue about it.

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@machadogj/arduino-and-node-js-via-serial-port-bcf9691fab6a).

Arduino code:

```
// Motor A connections
int enA = 9;
int in1 = 8;
int in2 = 7;
// Motor B connections
int enB = 3;
int in3 = 5;
int in4 = 4;
String var1;
const byte DATA_MAX_SIZE = 32;
char data[DATA_MAX_SIZE];   // an array to store the received data

void setup()
{
  // Set all the motor control pins to outputs
  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enB, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);

  // Turn off motors - Initial state
  digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
}
void receiveData() {
  static char endMarker = '\n'; // message separator
  char receivedChar;     // read char from serial port
  int ndx = 0;          // current index of data buffer  // clean data buffer
  memset(data, 32, sizeof(data));  // read while we have data available and we are
  // still receiving the same message.
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    receivedChar = Serial.read();    if (receivedChar == endMarker) {
      data[ndx] = '\0'; // end current message
      return;
    }    // looks like a valid message char, so append it and
    // increment our index
    data[ndx] = receivedChar;
    ndx++;    
    if (ndx >= DATA_MAX_SIZE) {
      break;
    }
  } 
  memset(data, 32, sizeof(data));
}
void loop()
{
  analogWrite(enA, 255);
  analogWrite(enB, 255);
  receiveData();
  if (data[0] == 'c') { //cc
    if (data[1] == 'c') {
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    }
    else if (data[1] == 'o') { //co
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, HIGH);
    }
  }
  else if (data[0] == 'w') { //wu
    if (data[1] == 'u') {
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
    }
    if (data[1] == 'd') { //wd
      digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
      digitalWrite(in4, HIGH);
    }
  }

  else {
    digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
    digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
  }
}
```

Node.js code:

```js
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = require('@serialport/parser-readline');const port = new SerialPort('COM3', { baudRate: 9600 });
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\n' }));
var stdin = process.stdin;

stdin.setRawMode( true );

stdin.resume();

stdin.setEncoding( 'utf8' );

  // on any data into stdin
stdin.on( 'data', function( key ){
//other if/elses
  if (key == 'j') {

        port.write('cc\n', (err) => {
          if (err) {
              return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
            }
              console.log('message written');
            });
  }
  if (key == 'l') {

        port.write('oc\n', (err) => {
          if (err) {
              return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
            }
              console.log('message written');
            });
  }
  if (key == 'i') {

        port.write('wu\n', (err) => {
          if (err) {
            return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
          }
            console.log('message written');
          });
  }
  if (key == 'k') {

        port.write('wd\n', (err) => {
          if (err) {
              return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
            }
              console.log('message written');
            });
  }
  if (key == '\u0003') { process.exit(); }

});
```

Comment: Can you please connect your arduino to PC and put some debug print inside the code, or can you provide a more specific description of the expected behaviour and of the actual one?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the very first line of code on the tutorial you said you followed:

```
 Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication
```

I'm not sure what RX LED you mean but it makes sense for it to blink because you're sending data from your computer but since the port is not initialized on your Arduino code the micro is not listening to the data so nothing is ever received.

Comment: Usually the the led flashes if some error is happening during the arduino execution and this make sense with your answer. After the fix everything should go fine

Comment: Yes, that might be the case too. I really have no idea because the question did not state what development board is being used...